# insertAll() not inserting entries into database

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I've created a database table that I am trying to add information too with a `onBeforeSaveElement()` hook.

For some reason, although it is telling me that the rows have been added in the `$result`, there is no records being added. Interestingly, if I run the page an then manually add a record to the database table, the `id` has been incremented by the amount of rows `$result` says it has added.. so it seems that the rows are being added then instantly deleted?

Thanks

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `craft_lsclearance` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` text,
  `cleared` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` char(36) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=229 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Function**

```
craft()->on('elements.onBeforeSaveElement', function(Event $event)
    {
        $element = $event->params['element'];
        $paths = craft()->plugin->getPaths($element);

        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $newPath = preg_replace('/site:/', '', $path['path'], 1);

            if ($path['locale'] != 'en') {
                $newPath = $path['locale'] . '/' . $newPath;
            }

            $model[] = array(UrlHelper::getSiteUrl($newPath));
        }

        $result = craft()->db->createCommand()->insertAll('lsclearance', array('path'), $model);

        print_r($model);
        echo '<br /> Inserted: ' . $result . 'row(s)';

        exit;

    }
);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/ ) 
  [1] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/ ) 
  [2] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/results?q=regatta+ac ) 
  [3] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/watch/regatta-ac-titanium/19225 ) 
  [4] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/mens-watches ) 
  [5] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/mens-watches/p2 ) 
  [6] => Array ( [0] => http://mydomain.com/watch/ac-ii/19282 ) 
) 
Inserted: 7 rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the element saving events (like `onBeforeElementSave()`, `onElementSave()`, `onBeforeSaveEntry()`..., etc. are all wrapped in a [database transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) (specifically encapsulated in the [CDbTransaction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTransaction) class).

When you call `exit`, you're killing the request and never giving a chance for the transaction to commit to the database.